# Could not open input file: artisan in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to run `composer update` command in my Laravel project. But I am getting below error.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Package jakub-onderka/php-console-color is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-color instead.
Package jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-highlighter instead.
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Could not open input file: artisan
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

[image]

Comment: And what's your question? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Can you show the contents of that directory, please? `ls -l`, if you can

Comment: Thanks @NicoHaase. I can't run `php artisan serve` command.

Comment: And what have you tried to debug that problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase, I don't know how to debug this issue.

Comment: Probably you deleted the artisan file from your repository. What laravel version you have installed? Check composer.json

Comment: Thanks @aynber. Here is the sreenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEoe3.png

Comment: You don't have `artisan`, which means your installation isn't complete. It's just a simple PHP file that you can download from https://github.com/laravel/laravel . **Just make sure you get the file from the correct version, which you can change in the Branch dropdown.**

Answer (score 0):

Both those packages are used by nunomaduro/collision which is a dependency of the Laravel framework. You can't really do anything about this at this point. The nunomaduro/collision needs to be updated with the new dependencies or updated dependencies.
besides it's just a warning, no need be scared about. Everything still works